# Estimating $\sum\limits _{n=1}^k \sin \frac x n$ in the form $f(k,x) \sin(g(k,x))$

Tags: summation, estimation

When you plot the function for a reasonably large $k$ ($300$ in this case) you get something like this...
[image: Plot of function for k=300]
This seemed like it could be estimated the way I stated previously. The accuracy of that estimation would be perfect at $x=0$ and deteriorate as you progressed from there.

I tried to tackle this with some brute force by computing roots and local max/minima and trying to find functions to their patterns. [Here's the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ybPQo3Ne3mcMkLjfnsSmdArXTEhWAGdMocZJBxTJGqc/edit?usp=sharing). The data is quite crude, it is just raw points and no local averaging was done.

1. The frequency of the estimation must very quickly reach a constant as $x$ is increased.
2. Derivative at $0=H_k$, where $H_k$ is the $k$th harmonic number.
3. The Position $(x,y)$ of the global maximum value is roughly $(0.62k, 0.58k)$.

EDIT:

4. For large $x$ and $k$, if $|x|>10k$ then

$$\sum \limits _{n=1} ^k \sin \frac x n \sim \frac {k^2} {k+x} \sin \left( \frac x k + \frac \pi 2 \right) .$$

So now we need a function that tends toward that for large $x$ and is accurate for small $x$.

I am wondering if there is a smarter way to find the final estimation (accurate for all $x$) like using a certain number of terms from the Taylor expansion for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: I think $\frac{10k}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\left[\frac{x}{k}-\frac{3}{2}\pi\right]$ works pretty well for large enough $k,x$.

Comment: Yes it seems that for sufficiently large x it is f(k,x) * sin[x/k -3/2 pi] but 10*sqrt[k] is much greater than the maximum height of the original function for large x. That helps a lot though thanks!

Comment: not $10\sqrt{k}$, but $10k/\sqrt{x}$ (**divided** by $\sqrt{x}$). I checked for $k\le 15000$ and $x\le 10^6$, and it works fine IMHO. I hope someone here can get a better estimate anyway

Comment: ah! sorry my mistake i read that root(x) as root(k) which I cancelled with the k on the numerator. Yes that does seem to work for those ranges, what i put in the edit under point 5 though is closer to the original function, for smaller k and x.

Comment: point 5 now point 4

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are seeking, but...

Let
$$h(x,k)=\sum\limits _{n=1}^k \sin \frac x n$$
and normalize it:
$$H(x,k)=\frac{1}{k}h(kx,k)=\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits _{n=1}^k \sin \frac{xk}{n}$$
This is a Riemann sum, so as $k\to \infty$ this tends to

$$H(x)=\int_0^1 \sin(x/t) \, dt = \sin(x) -x \,Ci(x)$$
where $Ci(x)$ is the [cosine integral function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CosIntegral.html).

The maximum occurs at $(0.6165,0.5782)$

[image]

Your approximation for large $x$, $\frac {k^2} {k+x} \sin \left( \frac x k + \frac \pi 2 \right)$, when normalized gives:

$$ H(x)\approx \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}$$
which is consistent with the graph:

[image]

Further, doing a [series expansion](http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Reference/AMS55.ASP?Res=150&Page=233) for large $x$ we get

$$ H(x) \approx \frac{1}{x}\left( \cos(x) + 2\frac{\sin(x)}{x} -6 \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} +\cdots \right)\approx  \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$$

For small $x$ (say $| x | < 1$) a series expansion gives:

$$ H(x) =-x \log(x) +x (1 -\gamma) +\frac{x^3}{12}+O(x^5)$$

Comment: Damn... I knew my pure maths wasn't up to this. Not sure what you mean by this not being exactly what I'm seeking, because it is! $f(x) = \sin(x) - xCi(x)$ and then evaluate $f(x/k)$ and that's the answer!

Comment: Sorry I meant $kf(x/k)$ not $f(x/k)$ See... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jOh8AK6gkwNHZ3OEd6MVlGODg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure. I meant that the solution does not lead directly to some sort of "modulated sinusoid" with some simple $f()$ and $g()$ functions, as you seemed to expect in the title.

Comment: True. I probably should have phrased it differently but I was more interested in the actual estimation than getting it in that form. I was conjecturing that that it could be solved that way because that was how I was tackling it, (Analysing data to see how "frequency" and "Amplitude" changed over x) but I was wrong. Maybe it could be made in that "modulated sinusoid" form, but that seems unlikely now.